# failed to install gems via bundler and heroku push rejected

Tags: ruby, heroku, rubygems, sinatra, bundler

I've tried updating the bundler and installing it, but it still fails. I've looked through everything I can find about this topic and it's not solving the problem.

Gemfile:

```
source 'http://isitup.org/rubygems.org'
gem 'sinatra', '1.3.3'
gem 'thin'
gem 'warden'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

And this is what happens when I run git push heroku master

```
Counting objects: 14, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11/11), 1.11 KiB, done.
Total 11 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rack app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.2.1
   Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs                            bin/ --deployment
   You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
   your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
   updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
   You have added to the Gemfile:
   * warden
   * bcrypt-ruby
   * pg
   * sqlite3
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rack app

To git@heroku.com:aqueous-wildwood-3092.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:aqueous-wildwood-3092.git'
```

Thanks.

Edit:
Getting an error while using `bundle install`

```
    Fetching gem metadata from http://isitup.org/rubygems.org/.
    Error TypeError during request to dependency API
    Fetching full source index from http://isitup.org/rubygems.org/
    Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler 
    troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks! 
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:540:in `initialize': not in gzip format         (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:540:in `new'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:540:in `gunzip'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:239:in `fetch_path'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:265:in `load_specs'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:231:in `block in list'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:227:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:227:in `list'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:216:in `fetch_all_remote_specs'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:89:in `rescue in specs'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:72:in `specs'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/source.rb:234:in `block in remote_specs'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/source.rb:232:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/source.rb:232:in `remote_specs'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/source.rb:165:in `fetch_specs'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/source.rb:70:in `specs'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:191:in `block (2 levels) in index'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:188:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:188:in `block in index'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/index.rb:9:in `build'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:184:in `index'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:178:in `resolve'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:113:in `specs'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:108:in `resolve_remotely!'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/installer.rb:81:in `run'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/installer.rb:14:in `install'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:230:in `install'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:275:in `dispatch'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:408:in `start'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/bin/bundle:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:4:in `with_friendly_errors'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/bin/bundle:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that currently http://rubygems.org is down. Check http://status.rubygems.org/

Bundler checks for dependencies there and if it can't get an answer it will fail subsequently. The rubygems people are investigating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to do `bundle install` before the push?

Comment: Yes I did trying 'bundle install' but that didn't solve the problem

Comment: could it be that the gemfile.lock wasn't added to the commit?

Answer (score 0):

Your Gemfile.lock is not updated with the latest changes you made to the Gemfile.

First try running the bundle install on your local machine, which will update your Gemfile.lock, then try pushing the code to heroku